# py2app Can't find Python Framework

Tags: python, frameworks, homebrew, py2app

I'm trying to use py2app to create a simple Python application on a Mac. I'm just trying to get py2app to work so right now my Python program looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
x = "hello"
print(x)
```

I'm running these commands in the terminal as per the py2app documentation:

```
py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py
python setup.py py2app -A
```

After I run these I get this error message.

```
MyApplication[57520:1908985] A Python runtime not could be located.  You may need to install a framework build of Python, or edit the PyRuntimeLocations array in this application's Info.plist file.
```

Looking in the *Info.plist*, these are the PyRuntimeLocations:

```
@executable_path/../Frameworks/libpython3.7.dylib
/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7.dylib
```

I have Python installed and I also tried installing it through homebrew (because I saw that as a solution for someone else) but it's not working for me. I've also tried editting the plist but that also did not get me anywhere.

Any ideas how I could get this working?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you have anaconda installed thanks to this

> /Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7.dylib

I had the same problem and I've just solve it.

I noticed that in my terminal this appeared [(base) tag in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRzrw.png)

And it gave me the same error that A Python runtime not could be located.
First I tried to do all my project in a virtual environment running python 3.9 and when I got to the

```
$ python setup.py py2app -A
```

It gave me the same error, but noticed that my terminal was looking like this [(env)(base) tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnJ4S.png)

As it were using two virtual environments, so in your terminal first run `$ your_environment deactivate` in case you are using a virtual environment and then you run `$ conda deactivate` which will get you out of the base environment conda get you in by default.

And finally you repeat the process of

```
$ python setup.py py2app -A
```

What happens is that if you're in the conda (base) venv, it will search the Framework in the opt directory without much success, but actually I will also recommend you to use a virtual environment for your project since you can use whatever python version you want and it's like a whole version packed in a directory with all the libraries you need so your app would be more independent with that.
If you've never used it don't worry it's pretty straight forward I'd just learned it myself two days ago to solve the exact same problem.

Hope I helped :)